# How do I print the number of occurences

Tags: java

I have to write a program using recursion, that prompts for a word and then counts the number of times the letter a appears in that word.

What do I need to type instead of + count + to make it work?

This is what I have so far;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    char p = 'a';
  }  

  public static int count (String line, char p){
    int len = line.length();
    if ((len == 0) || (p == '\0')){   // case for empty string or nil char.
        return 0;                     // recursion ends here
    }
    String rest = line.substring(1);
    if (line.charAt(0) == p) {
        return count(rest, p) + 1;   // recurse on substring
    } else {

    } // end of if-else

    return count(rest, p);   // recurse on substring

  }

  System.out.println("Character a occurs " + count + " times ");

}
```

Comment: Java ain't C - java doesn't have "nul terminated strings". Test for `.isEmpty()` or `== null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this at the bottom of your code:

```
{
   System.out.println("Character a occurs " + count + " times ");
}
```

And in your main method add the following line:

```
System.out.println("Character a occurs " + count(line,p) + " times ");
```

Comment: That worked! How can I change the char p = 'a'; so that it counts capital letters as well as lowercase? I tried char p = 'a' or 'A'; but no luck

Comment: Use this if statement: `if (line.charAt(0) == p || line.charAt(0) == Character.toUpperCase(p))  {` instead of your current one.

Comment: Thanks! It's fully working now. A few people have said I am not calling the method, but the program is fully functioning. Do you know why?

Comment: In your original program you did not call the method. However, in my proposed solution the method is called at `+ count(line,p) + `.

Comment: I see, thank you for helping with this. Is there a "best practice" for how to call the method? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: Depends on the circumstance

Answer (score 0):

You should cal the method count and display the result in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    char p = 'a';
    System.out.println("Character a occurs " + count(line, p) + " times ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have to recurse, it's just whether you increment or not. You should express it like that in code.

You replace your entire method with just one (readable) line:

```
public static int count(String line, char p) {
    return line.isEmpty() ? 0 : count(line.substring(1), p) + (line.charAt(0) == p ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Printing results to screen should be from your main method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems u have not called ur count method..

try this..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    char p = 'a';

    int count = count(line, p);

    System.out.println("Character a occurs " + count + " times ");

  }  
  public static int count (String line, char p)
  {
    int len = line.length();
    if ((len == 0) || (p == '\0'))   // case for empty string or nil char.
    return 0;                     // recursion ends here

    String rest = line.substring(1);
    if (line.charAt(0) == p)     
    {
      return count(rest, p) + 1;   // recurse on substring
    }
    else {

    } // end of if-else
    {
      return count(rest, p);   // recurse on substring
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is working without the "int count = count(line, p);" line, any idea why?

Comment: ur code wont work... it has last sysout line outside any method, so it wont compile itself...other than that u r trying to print count variable, which is not defined...

Comment: u need to call ur method somewhr else it wont get executed.. either while printing u can do count(line, p) or else u can call and store the return in some int variable...

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{
   static int counter=0;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    char p = 'a';
    count(line, p);
    System.out.println("Character a occurs " + counter + " times ");
  }  

  public static void count (String line, char p){
    int len = line.length();
    if ((len == 0) || (p == '\0')){   // case for empty string or nil char.
        return;                     // recursion ends here
    }
    String rest = line.substring(1);
    if (line.charAt(0) == p) {
        counter++;   // recurse on substring
    } else {

    } // end of if-else
    count(rest, p);   // recurse on substring
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your source code. You should try this on the short term, and reading Deitel&Deitel's Java How To Program book on the long term to improve your programming skills.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter String");

    System.out.println("Character a occurs " + ((Integer)count(input.nextLine(), 'a')).toString() + " times."); 

    input.close();
  }  

  public static int count (String line, char p){
    if (line.length() == 0) {   // base case: no more chars to look at
        return 0;
    }

    if (line.charAt(0) == p) {
        return count(line.substring(1), p) + 1;   // recurse on substring
    }
    else {
        return count(line.substring(1), p);   // recurse on substring
    }
  }
}
```